# Exponential y-axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, logarithm, exponential

I have some log-normal data. I would like to calculate means and confidence intervals on the log-scale and transform that for plotting on an the original scale. How can I do this in ggplot2?

Here's an example where I generate the log-normal dataset `D` with data for two groups, `A` with  and `B`, and plot the log-transformed data with confidence intervals:

```r
D = data.frame(y=exp(c(rnorm(10, 1), rnorm(10, 3))), x=rep(c('A', 'B'), each=10))
ggplot(D, aes(x=x, y=log(y))) + stat_summary(fun.data='mean_cl_boot')
```

In the solution I'm seeking the means would be `exp(1)` and `exp(3)` rather than `1` and `3` and confidence intervals which extends longer upwards than downwards.